# Sql Server Compact Limitations -- design decision or work in progress?

Tags: sql-server-ce, integration-testing, sql-server-ce-4

I'm using Sql Server Compact for automated integration tests of our web application, which runs the latest version of Sql Server (large? uncondensed?).  The idea was to use a more lightweight database to mimic our own, which would be easy to create and destroy for tests.

I'm aware of the [limitations that CE has in comparison to Sql Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896140%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx), and am willing to work around these by either trying to avoid the features that aren't supported in CE or working around the tests for the areas of our app that use these features.

My question, though: is there any reason to believe these limitations will eventually be overcome in future releases of Sql CE, or will I have to perpetually work around them for my testing needs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to perpetually work around them for your testing needs, and no future version of SQL Server Compact is planned