# Export SQL Server to SQL Server Compact 4.0 with VS Express

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-ce

I have created a C# application that connects to a Microsoft SQL Server Express Edition (64-bit) database. However, I want to transition the project from SQL Server to a local database and convert the `.mdf` file to a `.sdf` file.

The best solution I have found is [SQL Server Compact Toolbox](http://sqlcetoolbox.codeplex.com/) written by [ErikEJ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/183934/erikej) also pointed out by this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21288228/2145211). When attempting to install the add-in to Visual Studio I receive an error:

> This extension is not installable on any currently installed products.

even though the installer recognizes that Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Desktop is installed. I believe this is only targeted for Professional and above.

I have also attempted to use the standalone tool.  However, the option I want is grayed out and it's for version 3.5 instead of the current version 4.0.

[image]

I have also looked at trying to export/convert from Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio  11.0.3128.0. However, I have had no luck.

Is there a solution for VS Express Edition, or am I out of luck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the standalone edition for SQL Server Compact 4.0, available here: https://sqlcetoolbox.codeplex.com/releases/view/104096

Comment: That worked perfectly.  Thanks for your help and making the utility in the first place.

Comment: that link is broken. Maybe find it at https://github.com/ErikEJ/SqlCeToolbox